# Preparing explosion system by using asp.net mvc

Tags: system

I try to prepare a system that will eliminate all the world.

This system will be able to remove all people from the world.

However i have some question about this.

```
İf(Explosion==1)
{
// Remove people from the world.
}
else
{
// Remove specific human from the world.
}
```

Is it possible me to write this kind of system in asp.net mvc ?

Answer (score 0):

,Hi

This website helps people to do what they want in software.However we never think this kind of opinion against humans.We know that you try to kid with people, please do not share this kind of heart broker things.Also it is not suitable for this website.

Thanks.